# A JS library to add and remove and reposition HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a JS library that can add elements to the HTML, and remove them?

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child-1">
    <input name="child-1">
    <button>remove</button>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then if a user wants to drag-and-drop #child-1 element to another position, this will result in the order being changed.

Is there a library that can handle all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both to add/remove elements from the screen and drag-drop functionality jQuery can help to solve both problems.

- To remove/add - https://api.jquery.com/remove/
- Drag-drop - https://jqueryui.com/draggable/